# Firefox sync & xmarks

Tags: firefox

I was wondering if I can sign onto Firefox sync and/or X marks for bookmark sync between FF and Tor?

I have installed x marks on Tor but was wondering if it is right thing to do. So alternative would be to try and use Firefox sync

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10368

Answer (score 1):

Technically - yes, but - **strictly speaking** of privacy matters - you should not do so. If you'd like to sync your bookmarks - better use import-to-file/export-from-file tools of your choice, the file must be on a physical medium, not any kind of "online/cloud stuff". IMHO, just IMHO....